# Changing RSS feed URL structure

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess, rss, feed

I am in the process of creating a wordpress website, and I just have one issue left - RSS feeds.

Currently, the website has a `.htaccess` file blocking access to `/category/*` pages. It was part of a requirement that the site is not obviously Wordpress, and `/category` is a decent indicator of that.

Each category is fronted by a page, which displays the category content - so `/category/news` becomes `/news`.

However, RSS feeds always seem to point to `/category/xxx/feed` - is there a way to remove this `/category/` part? So people could view the RSS feed at `http://example.com/news/feed` ?

I've tried fiddling around with the `.htaccess` file, but it's the one area of building a web application I'm not 100% sure on. Every search has returned with results of how to point a feed to Feedburner instead, which is not what I am looking to do at all.

Comment: "It was part of a requirement that the site is not obviously Wordpress" Hopefully the people who made this a requirement understand that it has absolutely zero benefit in improving security, if that was the point.

Comment: So `/news` is just a `page`, not category `archive`? Hm, I can't think of an easy way to move a category feed in such fashion on WP level...

Comment: @Milo: No, that was not the point.

Comment: @Rarst Me either :(

Comment: You do know that you can change the tag and category slug prefixes on the permalinks settings page, right?

Comment: @Bjørn I don't think this is about moving archives themselves, but I might be misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found (in my opinion) the best and easiest way to do this, and thought I should leave it as an answer in case anybody stumbles upon this thread.

I downloaded and installed the [WP No Category Base](https://github.com/mines/no-category-base-wpml) plugin and that did exactly what I needed.

Unfortunately, I never got around to trying the other answers (had to move on to a more urgent project), so I can't clarify if any of them work.

---

**Updated Link**: [No Category Base (WPML)](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/)

Comment: @jgraup you should be able to find the plugin [here](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) now.

Comment: https://github.com/jonathantorres/JC-Garcia-Portfolio/tree/master/wp-content/plugins/no-category-base-wpml

Answer (score 1):

After some thought - this can be achieved with some creative abuse of existing feeds:

- easy part - redirect category feeds to page comment feeds
- hard part - make page comment feeds think they are category feeds

Something like this:

```
Category_Feed_At_Page::on_load();

/**
 * Repurpose page feeds for category of same name feeds.
 */
class Category_Feed_At_Page {

    static function on_load() {

        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( __CLASS__, 'pre_get_posts' ) );

        add_action( 'do_feed_rdf', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
        add_action( 'do_feed_rss', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
        add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
        add_action( 'do_feed_atom', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
    }

    /**
     * Change page's comment feed into category feed.
     *
     * @param WP_Query $query
     */
    static function pre_get_posts( $query ) {

        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_page() && $query->is_feed() ) {
            $name = $query->get( 'pagename' );

            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php' );

            if ( category_exists( $name ) ) {
                $category = get_category_by_slug( $name );

                $query->set( 'category_name', $name );
                $query->set( 'cat', $category->term_id );
                $query->set( 'pagename', '' );

                $query->is_page         = false;
                $query->is_comment_feed = false;
                $query->is_category     = true;
                $query->is_singular     = false;


                remove_action( 'do_feed_rdf', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
                remove_action( 'do_feed_rss', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
                remove_action( 'do_feed_rss2', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );
                remove_action( 'do_feed_atom', array( __CLASS__, 'do_feed' ), 9 );

                remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Redirect real category feed to page feed.
     */
    static function do_feed() {

        if ( ! is_category() )
            return;

        $name = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
        $page = get_page_by_path( $name );

        if ( ! empty( $page ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_post_comments_feed_link( $page->ID ) );
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rarst, I will have a go with this and see how it works :) If it does the trick I will come back and mark this as answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you can change the tag and category slug prefixes on the permalinks settings page, right?

So if it bothers you to have the "category" in "/category/news", but accepts having "/cat/news", you can change that there.

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. You will be able to leave [comments](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) when you gain some reputation on site. (undeleted since made more answer-ish :)